# How jump to value in INSERT statement in IntelliJ IDEA query console?

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, plugins, datagrip

Well, I've too long **INSERT** statement in IntelliJ query console.

```
INSERT INTO some_table(a, b, c,…)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 3,…)
```

When I put cursor on specific column or related value - thanks IDEA - it highlights to me this relation:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR92y.png)

But what if statement contains many columns/values, that don't fit on the screen?

I wanna have possibility jump to value, associated with column, on which the cursor is located, or see value in Popup, like 'Quick Definition' action (Ctrl+Shift+I; Win).

So, tell me please, is there such action/hotkey or plugin, that allows to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no functionallity of that kind in JetBrains IDEs. Can we ask you to create a feature request?

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

Comment: Perhaps, in free time later I will create it: too busy right now.
Thank you for clarifying.